# Zypper repository authentication (non-interactive)

Tags: authentication, docker, sles, zypper

I need to add a repository using zypper that requires authentication from a Dockerfile. I'm able to add it, but of course, when I try to run

`zypper -n refresh`

It fails because the authentication failed.

What is the normal approach to automate the authentication process? Didn't find a good answer while "googling".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it like this:

**Dockerfile**

```
ARG MY_REPO_USERNAME
ARG MY_REPO_PASSWORD

RUN zypper -n addrepo https://$MY_REPO_USERNAME:$MY_REPO_PASSWORD@repo.domain/foo/bar repo-domain-alias
```

When building the image:

```
docker build --build-arg MY_REPO_USERNAME=my_username --build-arg MY_REPO_PASSWORD=my_password -tag my-image-name .
```